# Personal Custom Card Game

Tags: game-design, legal, card-game

I had the idea, to make a custom card game based off an Anime i like. I was wondering if it would be legal to have such printed out (using a custom card/board game service) for personal use. I would only play it with friends and not make any money off of it.

Comment: @Byte56, is this question is a duplicate of a duplicate?

Comment: @Ocelot The question more closely matches the duplicate, yes. But the question behind the question is a duplicate of both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A printer service probably don't want to print such cards. I am not a lawyer, but the way it has been explained to me is that from a legal perspective, they print the cards and *sell them to you*. If you have them print cards of your design you basically license them to print that design on a set of cards. 
The printer could be in legal trouble if they print stuff and sell the printed materials to you.

Quote from The Game Crafter:

*Can I make a game using copyrighted items if I don't intend to sell it to others?*
We are **not** able to print games containing copyrighted items used without permission, **even if they are intended for personal use only**.
https://www.thegamecrafter.com/help/intellectual-property

It doesn't mean *all* print-on-demand services verify or comply to this, but this is the legal stuff what I understood from TGC staff.

Some services out there try to move the legal burden to you by having you tick a box "yes I own all rights", but in the end AFAIK the printer could still be sued for infringement if they knowingly print and sell you the stuff.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into the various services and their specifics.